# For a symmetric positive definite matrix $A$, prove that the matrix $A_2 - l\cdot u$ is also symmetric positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm talking about the [recursive way to find an LU decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#Through_recursion).

So I need to prove that, given a symmetric positive definite matrix $A$; the matrix we get from going 1 step into the recursion $A_2 - l\cdot u$ is also symmetric positive definite. $A_2$ is the matrix we get from "taking out" the first column and row from $A$. $l$ is the first column in $L$, taking out first element. $u$ is the first row in $u$, taking out first element.

We didn't really learn a lot of sentences about PD matrices, besides working with the definition; so I tried doing it in the simplest way - writing a general symmetric A matrix, and working up the  algorithm steps to get to the general $A_2 - l\cdot u$. And it is symmetric, but I can't say anything about it being PD, it's too messy and ugly, I doubt it's the way to the solution.

Would really like to hear input about this, thank you all in advance

Comment: The Doolittle algorithm as I learnt didn't really care about positive definiteness, or even symmetry

Comment: @FShrike sorry, wrong algorithm. I meant the recursive method of finding an LU, as depicted in the link